# How to get unique dates based on from_date and to_date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

```
from_date       to_date      duration 
-------------------------------------
2018-10-01      2018-10-10      9
2018-10-05      2018-10-07      3
```

If I provide input `@from_date = 2018-10-01, to_date = 2018-10-11`, I want to display count as 9

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using ? Each one has different dates methods .

Comment: Thanks for dumping your problem. Can you share your attempt at it?

Comment: @dfundako He didn't even do that right .

Comment: The data is incorrect. Either the first row is 9 or the second row is 3.

Comment: @SalmanA corrected above

Comment: Just `SELECT from_date, to_date, DATEDIFF(DAY, from_date, to_date)`... No?

Comment: "9 and 3" is just as wrong as "10 and 2".  It's either inclusive or exclusive to the dates on the end.  _Seems_ like you might be going for "10 and 3"

Comment: guys, did u understand the problem?

Comment: These duration values are inconsistent.

Comment: @sandyhrk . . . I would suggest that you ask another question.  Please explain the logic of getting a "count" of 9.  It looks suspiciously like the first duration value, but that is only a guess.  Are you looking for the first match in the table or for some more complicated logic?

Comment: @BartoszSiemasz yes

Answer (score 1):

How about that:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,'20181001','20181011')-1
```

Comment: Why would you create a function that merely calls another function?

Comment: how to exclude the second row?

Comment: @sandyhrk perhaps try rephrasing your question as it seems dubiously simple and has been answered, but judging from your comments it appears you are still lacking something from the provided answer.

Comment: @ChadEstes  i need to return a single value as count. while considering two rows

Comment: @sandyhrk  Then how is that single value derived?  Is it a sum of the differences between the two date columns in each row, a maximum of the differences, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

```
--To select a single value per row
SELECT 
  DATEDIFF(DAY,from_date,to_date) as duration
FROM 
  SomeTable
```

You could apply a WHERE clause to filter to just a specific row that you want the duration of returned or wrap the DATEDIFF function in an AVG() or SUM() to get the avergae or total of all the durations in the table.  You can do all kinds of very complex things with T-SQL.  For instance the below query will get you the average duration for each month when whatever was started (from_date) for the year 2017.

E.G. -

```
SELECT  
  DATEPART(Month, from_date) as Month, 
  AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, from_date, to_date) as AvgDuration
FROM SomeTable
WHERE 
  DATEPART(Year, from_date) = 2017
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(Month, from_date)
```

Hope this helps.  If not, feel free to try again. :)

Comment: i need to get unique dates ( date difference count) in that table.